# Bacula bconsole doesn't connect to localhost Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, bacula

I've recently installed Bacula on Centos7 Cloud HaaS from digital ocean. However, all the tests and steps were done correctly, the problem is when I try to connect to bacula's console using the command:

```
sudo bconsole
```

I get Connecting to Director localhost:9101 and nothing happens.

If i try listening:

```
netstat -ltnp
```

No outputs are present from the port 9101

After trying debugging using:

```
bacula-dir -d 100 -c /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf
```

I get the following output:

```
bacula-dir: dird.c:223-0 Debug level = 100

[root@panel ~]# 14-أكت 11:37 bacula-dir: ERROR TERMINATION at bsys.c:484
```

bacula-dir is already running. pid=2458
Check file /var/run/bacula-dir.9101.pid

Any clue what to do in order to get the bconole to work?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Database user was not connected to the configuration files.

To fix this login to mysql as root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your root password, then create a DB user and password for Bacula.

(Assuming you already entered your db password inside "bacula-sd.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Now lets set Bacula to use the Mysql library:

```
su -c 'alternatives --config libbaccats.so'
```

This should show you the following:

There are 3 programs which provide ‘libbaccats.so’.

```
  Selection    Command
————————————————————————
    1           /usr/lib64/libbaccats-mysql.so
    2           /usr/lib64/libbaccats-sqlite3.so
*+  3           /usr/lib64/libbaccats-postgresql.so

Hit 1 and press enter to select MySql.
```